# Some Services Not Showing With Get-Service cmdlet in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, services

I am trying to compile a list of services on several different servers running Windows Server 2019. To do this I have been to outputting the service names using `Get-Service` in Powershell but on one of the machines there is a specific set of services that just aren’t coming up in the list. Is there some known reason (config?) this might occur or have I been unfortunate enough to hit an unusual bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake. I was filtering for a common word using the `-Name` parameter, when what I wanted was `-Displayname`.

Comment: and that is why you ALWAYS post the code you are actually running ... [*grin*]